# How to come up with this recurrence relation for putting p rooks in a m×n chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a **m**×**n** chessboard and I have to put **p** rooks in the board so that no two of them are in attacking position.
(*Two rooks attack each other if they are in the same row or same column*)
How many ways I can do that?
I saw somewhere that the problem can be described with a recurrence relation which would be ***R(m,n,p) = m . R(m-1,n-1,p-1) + R(m,n-1,p)*** .
I tried to figure it out but I couldn't.
How did this relation come?(I know the base cases, I just want to know how this formula works?)

EDIT : I have considered it already but that's where my confusion is.
 Let's say I have a 3×3 chessboard. 
[image]
Then when I want to put rooks in the first column I have 3 options (choosing cell 1,1 ; choosing cell 2,1 ; choosing cell 3,1) .
Now,from my poor drawing it's obvious when I'm putting the rook in the cell (1,1) or (3,1) I just have to find out how many ways I can put other (one less) rooks in the (2×2) chessboard.
But when I'm putting the rook in the cell (2,1) I see I have to find out how many ways I can put ***x*** rooks in a 1×2 chessboard and ***y*** rooks in a 1×2 chessboard.

Where,x+y = p - 1.
Now for any ***m*** and ***n*** this new recurrence relation has to be true ***R(m,n,k) = R(t,n,x) + R(m-t,n,k-x)*** .

Because if that's true then for placing every rook in the first column I can surely assume I can place other rooks in R(m-1,n-1,p-1) ways.

(I am not sure how this works and how x and y would vary.)

That's where I got stuck.

Comment: The two disconnected parts behave just like a 2 times 2 square as far as the rules of this task are concerned. So, while it isn't a rectangle you can treat it like it were one.

Comment: Yeah I got this now.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you have $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

Case 1: There is a rook in the first column

This gives $m$ possibilities for placing this rook and $R(m-1,n-1,p-1)$ for placing the other rooks. (One rook less, remove first column, remove row with the first rook.)

Case 2: There is no rook in the first column

This is clearly the same problem with $n$ replaced by $n-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I have considered it already.I just didn't get the Case 1.